# Jubula consumes ~20GB on my hard drive for logging. I've never used it.

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, jubula

I performed a HDD scan to see what consumes my space on my dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and found out a directory `/home/user/.jubula/logs` that gets ~20 gb of my space.

So, what is Jubula and how can it consume 20gb for logging when I have never used it?

Comment: I suppose you can disable it, however

Comment: Thank you for your answer Manuel! Yes, I know that, but still, how can it get 20 gb for logging since I haven't used it so far? I mean, I never wrote a testing code so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably your client's log which is large. The application you're testing must have a lot of log output, which is also saved into this folder. (files like rc_*.log)

You could write a batch script to remove it regularly; like at every launch. There's not much need to keep this log when you launch an AUT from the beginning again.

You could also delete the AUT agent's logs if you have a working AUT configuration. (client.log) Anyways, if you want to track why a test failed, the test results are kept in the database.

Comment: Application Under Test. The application you are running your tests against. Something (or someone) is running tests (or used to run) on your machine that produces the output. I think it's worth reading a few lines from these logs to find out when those tests were performed on what kind of application.

Comment: good idea, i'll try to open it but with 20gb i'm afraid it will freeze my system :P